# Python: Indexing a file that is tab delimited

Tags: python, indexing

I have a text file that is tab delimited and looks like:

> 1_0     NP_045689       100.00  279   0       0       18      296     18    296     3e-156   539
>
> 1_0     NP_045688       54.83   259   108     6       45      296     17    273    2e-61    224

I need to parse out specific columns such as column 2.

I've tried with the code below:

```
z = open('output.blast', 'r')
for line in z.readlines():
    for col in line:
        print col[1]
z.close()
```

But i get a index out of range error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). That should help you a lot if you plan on doing more stuff with your tab-delimited files, too. One nice thing is that you can assign names to the various columns.

Answer (score 7):

```
z = open('output.blast', 'r')
for line in z.readlines():
    cols = line.split('\t'):
        print cols[1]
z.close()
```

You need to `split()` the line on tab characters first.

Alternatively, you could use Python's [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module in tab-delimiters mode.

Comment: This will print out the second letter in every column - this is not what you intent I am sure.

Comment: Whoops. The danger of copy paste. :) Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
import csv,StringIO
text="""1_0 NP_045689   100.00  279 0   0   18  296 18  296 3e-156  539
1_0 NP_045688   54.83   259 108 6   45  296 17  273 2e-61   224"""

f = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(text), delimiter='\t')
for row in f:
    print row[1]
```

two things of note:

the delimiter argument to the reader method tells the csv module how to split the text line. Check the other arguments to the reader function to extend functionality (ie: quotechar)

I use StringIO to wrap the text example as a file object, you dont need that if you are using a file reference.

ex:

```
f=csv.reader(open('./test.csv'),delimiter='\t')
```

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered, but I thought I'd share the use of namedtuples for this sort of situation, as it allows pleasant object.attribute type attribute access.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
rec = namedtuple('rec', 'col1, col2, col3, col4, col5')
for r in map(rec._make, csv.reader(open("myfile.tab", "rb"), delimiter='\t')):
    print r.col2, r.col5
```

See the Python [collections documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is why your code is going wrong:

```
for col in line:
```

will iterate over every CHARACTER in the line.

```
    print col[1]
```

A character is a string of length 1, so col[1] is always going to give an index out of range error.

As others have said, you either need to split the line on the TAB character `'\t'`, or use the csv module, which will correctly handle quoted fields that may contain tabs or newlines.

I also recommend avoiding using readlines - it will read the entire file into memory, which may cause problems if it is very large.  You can iterate over the open file a line at a time instead:

```
z = open('output.blast', 'r')
for line in z:
    ...
```